# How to center a Kineticjs image from a jsonObject file?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, json

I have images loaded from a jsonObject file with a dimension width: 26 height: 26, and I wanna center the image objects from the jsonObject file.
I tried to put width 10 and height 10, but It only crops the images from width: 26 height: 26 to width: 10 and height: 10, It dont place the images in the center.

```
kinImages[index] = new Kinetic.Image({

    image: theImage,
    x: jsonObjectsLoaded[index].x,
    y: jsonObjectsLoaded[index].y,
    name: jsonObjectsLoaded[index].name,
    width: 10,
    height: 10
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To place the images in the center you have to change `x` and `y` values, not width and height. Set them to the stage center.